# breeze entity creation, foreign key column is set to "0" by default

Tags: breeze

i've got some FK's in a table which are not nullable.
i've checked in the model and on the database and the FK's are set to not nullable and have no default values assigned.

now when i create a breeze entity of this type the FK Columns are already filled with "**0**"

i would like to post some pictures here but my reputation doen't allow me to do so.

i've checked the validators and they are there (one of type required and one of type int32) but they will sadly never kick in because the value is already "0"

so i don't get validation errors clientside but i get them when going back to the server.

btw. i'm using web api entity framework, ms sql2008r2 and i've tried with breeze.debug.js 1.4.5, 1.4.6 and the one now on github which should have getValidationErrors() fixed.

thats how i create the entity:

```
function newDiscount() {

    var dsc = manager.createEntity("tblTransactionImporterDiscounts");
    return dsc;
}
```

this smells like a bug. any enlightment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you insert: `console.log(dsc.foreignKeyName());` between those two lines in function `newDiscount`? To me, it sounds like you have something like: `<input type="number" data-bind="value: dsc.foreignKeyName"></input>`. This would automatically assign 0 to any null value.

Comment: `function newDiscount() {

            var dsc = manager.createEntity("tblTransactionImporterDiscounts");
            console.log(dsc.IDCampaignType);
            return dsc;
        }`

Comment: yeah :) looks like enter key directly sends the comment...anyway output is as well "0"

Comment: Do you have default value set to 0?

Comment: thanks for catching up on this.
no, there are no defaults set. 
model: http://pastebin.com/PGCkgNwJ
dbscript: http://pastebin.com/gRZFMhUd
breeze metadata: http://pastebin.com/hjutfXFf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an entity Breeze always initializes the value of all of its fields.

1. If there is a default value defined for the field ( part of the EntityType/DataProperty metadata) then this value is used.
2. If not then the default value for the field's datatype is used.

   1. For a nullable field this value is 'null'
   2. For a nonnullable field  then

      1. For a nonnullable numeric field this default value is the number 0. **(This is your case)**
      2. For a nonnullable string field this default value is an empty string ('').
         etc..

So you have a couple of choices. Either make the field nullable or add a custom validation that stipulates that a value of 0 is not valid for this field.

See the [validation documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation#refNav) for an extended discussion on this point as it relates to reference navigation properties.

Comment: thanks @Dominictus and you Jay.
i've got now a working solution for my "super straight forward data driven data entry grid" ;)
i'm setting all the properties which are not nullable to null when creating them: 
`var dsc = manager.createEntity("tblTransactionImporterDiscounts", { IDCampaignType: null , IDImporterDiscount: null ,Discount: null});`
this results in validationerrors which results in a nice grid where all the needed fields of a new row are colored automatically

Comment: @fops While your solution works, I still prefer a validator to nulling the FK value. See the discussion in the [validation documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation#refNav)

Comment: @ward Seems to me that the problem is that breeze should initialize non-nullable properties to null.  That may sound weird, but using any other value is asking for trouble -- accidentally saving a record with _bad_ data.  Seems that it's better to fail save (since a non-nullable property is null) than to accidentally save a value that is valid (passes validation) but is arbitrary WRT the application.  IMO, it's dangerous that breeze has a default for the default value.

Comment: FYI: Here is a request to change breeze to use null for nonnullable properties: http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5118106-entity-creation-initialise-foreign-key-properti

Comment: @Ward Do you guys have any updates on whether you even consider NOT to set nonnullable properties to values which pass validation upon an entity creation? It's completely wrong to allow to successfully save an entity with required fields just after its creation. I don't have any use case in my mind when this behavior is desirable. How to change this behavior with Breeze 1.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace ProvSys.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblTransactionImporterDiscounts
    {
        public int IDTransactionImporterDiscount { get; set; }
        public int IDImporterDiscount { get; set; }
        public int IDCampaignType { get; set; }
        public string CampaignText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Discount { get; set; }
        public int IDTransaction { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReceivedOn { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IDCampaignType")]
        public tblCampaignTypes tblCampaignTypes { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IDImportedDiscount")]
        public tblImporterDiscounts tblImporterDiscounts { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IDTransaction")]
        public tblTransactions tblTransactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, since it is not nullable, my assumption is that you don't want to save null values anyway and you should know what foreign keys you want to attach to new object. Try adding something like this to creating function:

```
function newDiscount(transaction, campaign, importedDiscount) {
    var dsc = manager.createEntity("tblTransactionImporterDiscounts");
    dsc.IDCampaignType = campaign.id;
    dsc.IDImportedDiscount = importedDiscount.id;
    dsc.IDTransaction = transaction.id;
    return dsc;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the model gets created from the db automatically.
not sure i should change the model.
the reason i want to have a validation error in this case is that i'm using a simple check function which gets used from the angular binding.
if the check function returns false the input field in this case gets automatically (angular) marked as red.
it works already for other fields which should not be null.
imaging adding a new row and immediately you see the fields which needs values and everything taken from the metadata...pretty slick or what do you think?

Comment: the value "0" makes no sense to me. it's not even a valid id to a related entity. so why is there this "0"? :)
if it would be initialised with null and if an entity gets created there would be validationErrors because the required-validator would kick in and would mark my entryfields automatically so the user sees that there is an input needed.